# How do I solve this unique constraint error?

Tags: sql, database, create-table

I am running a python code in jupyter lab. I am trying to create a table from other tables in a database file. This is my code:

```
# Alternative INVENTORY_PARENTLOT table

c.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS inventory_parentlot")
query = """
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_inv_parents AS SELECT a.id, b.inventorytype AS type, a.parentid FROM inventory_parents AS a JOIN table_inventory AS b on a.id=b.id JOIN table_inventory AS c on a.parentid=c.id WHERE c.inventorytype > 12 ;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_inv_parents2 AS SELECT a.id, a.type, b.parentid FROM tmp_inv_parents AS a JOIN tmp_inv_parents AS b on a.parentid = b.id;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_inv_parents3 AS SELECT a.id, a.type, b.parentid FROM tmp_inv_parents2 AS a JOIN tmp_inv_parents2 AS b on a.parentid = b.id;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_inv_parents4 AS SELECT a.id, a.type, b.parentid FROM tmp_inv_parents3 AS a JOIN tmp_inv_parents3 AS b on a.parentid = b.id;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_inv_parents5 AS SELECT a.id, a.type, b.parentid FROM tmp_inv_parents4 AS a JOIN tmp_inv_parents4 AS b on a.parentid = b.id ;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_inv_parentall AS SELECT * from tmp_inv_parents UNION SELECT * from tmp_inv_parents2 UNION SELECT * from tmp_inv_parents3 UNION SELECT * from tmp_inv_parents4;

CREATE TABLE inventory_parentlot AS SELECT a.id, b.id AS parentlot FROM (select id, min(parentserial) as firstparentserial FROM (select a.id, a.parentid, b.idserial AS parentserial from tmp_inv_parentall AS a JOIN table_inventory AS b on a.parentid = b.id ORDER BY a.id) GROUP BY id) AS a JOIN table_inventory AS b on a.firstparentserial = b.idserial;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX inventory_parentlot_id ON inventory_parentlot(id);

ANALYZE inventory_parentlot;

"""

c.executescript(query)
```

When this code runs, I get a unique constraint error. However, I have checked each table and the ids are unique.

How can I solve this? Is there a way I can just ignore the error?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the id is unique in the outer query of the SQL that creates the tabel.

```
CREATE TABLE inventory_parentlot AS 
SELECT a.id, MAX(b.id) AS parentlot 
FROM (
   SELECT id, MIN(parentserial) AS firstparentserial 
   FROM (  
      SELECT a.id, a.parentid, b.idserial AS parentserial 
      FROM tmp_inv_parentall AS a 
      JOIN table_inventory AS b ON a.parentid = b.id
   ) 
   GROUP BY id
) AS a 
JOIN table_inventory AS b 
  ON a.firstparentserial = b.idserial
GROUP BY a.id;
```

Comment: This worked great! Thank you!!

Comment: Well, it avoids the error by making the id's unique in the result.But whether MIN/MAX gets the correct inventory id, that's for you to decide.